# Is there a good way to make conditional column names that reference a list in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of items that would like to check my field titled 'events' for. my desired output is another field in the table for each item in my list, which contains a count of that item for each row. I have little experience writing for loops and am stuck, but below is the logic of what I'm looking for.

```
events <- c('screen_view','cta','os_update')
    
    
    for (i in events) {
      
      event_data_consumer$i <- str_count(event_data_consumer$event,'i')
    
    }
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Possibly in apply/lapply etc ?

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop code had two issues - 1) `$i` - will literally create a column `i` instead of the value from for each loop.  Here, we can use `[[`. 2) `'i'` will again be taken string "i" instead of the value, so we don't need a quoted value

```
library(stringr)
for(i in events) {
    event_data_consumer[[i]] <- str_count(event_data_consumer$event, i)
}
```

---

Or with `lapply`, loop over the vector of `events` with `lapply`, get the count of strings from the 'event' column and assign it to new columns in the data with `[`

```
event_data_consumer[events] <- lapply(events, function(x)
             str_count(event_data_consumer$event, x))
```